# Nuxt- How to fix when go to production it request incorrect?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, production-environment, production

How can I fix my site when going to production it requests URL from localhost but some endpoint requests correctly

[image: Incorrect Request Image]

[image: Correct Request Image]

Comment: You can use base url window.location.origin for requesting to server.

Comment: Without the actual code (as text) or a [repro], it will be hard to help you here. Also, try to debug the thing locally (will be faster).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.